# renderer2 selectRootElement() did not match any elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am creating a little webpage which needs to use dynamically created element inside the div. I want to render buttons in .ts file but  I am getting

> ERROR Error: The selector "myDIV" did not match any elements

Here's the example adding simple text in .ts file:

```
  renderButtons(){
    const element = this.renderer.selectRootElement('myDIV');
    const text = this.renderer.createText('something');
    this.renderer.appendChild(element, text); 
  }
```

.html file:

```
<div id="myDIV"> 

</div>
```

Regards

Comment: do you want to change components dynamically or is it that  just its one component you want to show or hide

Comment: I need to do dynamically pagination on 5,10, 25  elements in one page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it in wrong way, define your dynamic elements INSIDE html template e.g.

```
<div id="myDIV"> 
    <button *ngIf="showButton==true">myButton</button>
    <ng-container *ngIf="showText==true">{{ myText }}</ng-container>
</div>
```

where `myText`, `showButton` and `showText` are fields of component defined inside .ts file. The `<ng-container>` put content (text) without creating html element (like div/span)

If you want to use many elements - define one element as separate component and use it in parent component html template as follows

```
<myElement *ngFor="let item in elementsDataArray" [data]="item"></myElement>
```

where `elementsDataArray` is array defined in parent .ts file, which contains objects (items) with data used in you myElement component and bind to its parameter `data`.